# Is it possible to add data to view data from controller constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, constructor

I have a data that I want to return in all of my controller methods and I thought that'd be cleaner to return from the controller's constructor; because currently it's just repetitive return code.

```
protected $data;

public function __construct() {
   $this->data = "Test";
}

public function index() {
   // Stuff

   return view('test')->with([
       'testData' => $this->data
        // other view data
   ]);
}

public function store() {
   // Stuff

   return redirect()->back()->with([
       'testData' => $this->data
        // other view data
   ]);
}
```

<sub>This is just a pseudo example.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. It's done exactly in the same manner you showed.

However, I don't think that's the best way to do it. You might want to take a look into [ViewComposers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers), which help provide a data set to a view (or multiple views) right after the controller but before the view is finally provided to the user.

Comment: I know about ViewComposers - but for this example, I don't want to return the data to all my views in my application; I want to do it in a couple of Controllers only - So I don't have to write `testData' => $this->data` in every controller I have. Is it possible to achieve it with ViewComposers or is it application-wide for all views?

Comment: ViewComposers allow you to return it to all views, indeed, but you'd have to specify that every view relies on said composer. What you want seems a little more oriented to something that **all** views can access, so it might be better then to add a shared variable within the `AppServiceProvider`. In the `boot` method, you can use `view->share('var_name', 'value')`. This can be used within **any** view. Be mindful of naming it something specific enough so it doesn't fail though

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a controller method to append the data property for you:

```
protected function view($name, $data = []) 
{
    return view($name, $data + $this->data);
}

public function index() {
    ...
    return $this->view('view', ['other' => 'data']);
}
```

Comment: This is also an interesting approach

Comment: This would be easier to control data at a controller level than a view composer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewComposer` which allow you to attach data to the view every time certain views is rendered

```
namespace App\ViewComposers;
class DataComposer
{

    protected $data = ['1', '2', '3']; // This data is just for sample purpose

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('data', $this->data);
    }
}
```

And to register this composer with the list of all views on which the data must by attached add this code in the `boot` method off the `AppServiceProvider`

```
View::composer(
    ['view1', 'view2', 'view3', '....'],
    'App\ViewComposers\DataComposer'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very much possible with the code you have

[EDIT]
If you wish to remove `['testData' => $this->data]` from all controller methods, then you can use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers).

View composers are linked to `one view`. So for that view, if you have the same set of data to be passed all the time, use view composers!

Comment: Yes, but I was asking to remove `'testData' => $this->data` part from all the controller methods and only keep it in constructor

Comment: Oh yes, you can use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers)

Comment: Aren't ViewComposers for global app-wide views? Is it possible to use it for only one controller or few controllers and not all?

Comment: View composers are linked to `one view`. So for that view, if you have the same set of data to be passed all the time, use view composers

Answer (score 0):

create a [after middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#defining-middleware)  However, this middleware would perform its task after the request is handled by the application